# Organizing ranef.mer in ascending or descending order

Tags: lme4

I'm trying to figure out how to organize the ranef.mer list of random effects from a simple lmer model with only random intercepts and one variable (sex).

```
fit.b <- lmer(Math ~ 1 + Sex + (1+Sex|SchoolID), data=pisa_com, REML=FALSE)
```

I've plotted the random effects using qqmath, but I either need to be able to label each of the random effects by their cluster number (in this case, schools), or organize the ranef.mer output.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this last night. The ranef.mer can be coerced into a dataframe.

I fit the model:

```
fit.b <- lmer(Math ~ 1 + Sex + (1+Sex|SchoolID), data=pisa_com, REML=FALSE)
```

Then coerced it into a dataframe by including the identifying variable

```
random.effects <- as.data.frame(ranef(fit.b)$SchoolID)
```

Then write it to a .csv for sorting in excel

```
write.csv(random.effects, file="~/folder/file.name.csv")
```

Comment: ?? (1) the elements of `ranef()` should already be data frames (which version of lme4 are you using)? (2) you should be able to sort it in R perfectly easily ... I find `plyr::arrange` particularly convenient, e.g. `plyr::arrange(ranef(fm1)$Subject,\`(Intercept)\`)` for the `fm1` created by `example(lmer)`